# SQL server time related

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to take the fields from 9 PM to 11 Am from a table for a month in sql server 2008.

I tried

```
 SELECT * FROM your_table 
WHERE DateCol between  (DateCol=cast (GETDATE() as DATE) AND TimeCol<'21:00:00') and 
(DateCol=cast (GETDATE() as DATE) AND TimeCol<'11:00:00') and Datecol between '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000' and '2014-01-31 23:59:59.760'
```

For a month, the fields from the time of 9PM t0 11 AM

Comment: Can you better explain your question? It is not clear

Comment: `select *,cast(Datecol as time) as datecol1,cast(Datecol as date) as datecol2 from table where datecol1 between 21:00:00 and 11:00:00  and datecol2 between <rest >`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this !

```
 ;with cte as
    (
    select *,cast(Datetime_col as time) as X1,cast(Datetime_col as date) as X2 from table001
    )

    select * from cte where X1 between 21:00:00 and 11:00:00  and X2 between 01-jan-2014 and 31-jan-2014
```

### <kbd>[Read this for date formats](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)</kbd>

Comment: thank you sir, it works for me. but the problem is time range is not accepting. only it takes from 9AM to 11PM. Not as per my condition. I need it from 11PM to next day 9AM. Can you please help me.

Comment: Yes Done. And my second condition is still pending. can you please go through it ?

Comment: Ys Am on it, Lemme try this appending the other condition too. Thanks for your patiency